# FlurryAgent.getAd always returns false

Tags: android, flurry

I'm trying to implement flurry ads in my android app. I have a problem - `FlurryAgent.getAd always returns false`

I have banner "FrameLayout" and I'm trying to put these some ads.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FlurryAgent.initializeAds(this); 
        boolean result = FlurryAgent.getAd(this, "ingame", (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.bannerframe), FlurryAdSize.BANNER_BOTTOM, 1000);
        Log.d("FlurryAgent", "FlurryAgent getAd " + result);
    }
```

The result in log is (It's my logs, not native flurry):

```
04-19 14:44:38.367: E/FlurryAgent(13675): FlurryAgent setFlurryKey ---------
04-19 14:44:38.460: E/FlurryAgent(13675): FlurryAgent onStartSession
04-19 14:44:39.484: D/FlurryAgent(13675): FlurryAgent getAd false
```

I've tried setTestAds(true) - no difference.

Comment: Did you miss adding line `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context, apiKey)` before the line `FlurryAgent.initializeAds(this)`

Comment: Ye can see the logs - onStartSession is called

Comment: But i don't see that line in your code :P

Comment: It's actually in super.onStart(); `Log.e("FlurryAgent", "FlurryAgent onStartSession");
   FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, flurryKey);
         FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
   FlurryAgent.onEvent(pageName() + " shown");
   FlurryAgent.onPageView();`

Comment: Add this line and tell me what its returning `FlurryAgent.isAdAvailable(Context context, String adSpace, FlurryAdSize size, 
    long timeout)`

Comment: make sure that adSpace is same as you defined in flurry website

Comment: `FlurryAgent.isAdAvailable(this, "ingame", FlurryAdSize.BANNER_BOTTOM, 1000);` returns false. Here is the settings of app space. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e516lv57b

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28510/discussion-between-flexdroid-and-yanny)